# Java 8 lambda reverse operation to Collectors.groupingBy

Tags: lambda, java-8

I have a entity class

```
public class User {
  private String name;
  private List<String> adress;

  // gertters and setters
}
```

Basically, the above class give a list of adress grouped by user name.
I need transform `class User` in `class User2`. Look:

```
public clas User2 {
  private String name;
  private String address;
}
```

Where a User object with five address will be generate a five User2 objects.

If a have a list of User, is there a way to do that with a single Java 8 Lambda expression?

I was trying to do

```
userList.stream().reduce( ?????? ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I could come up with:

```
userList.stream().<User2> flatMap(
                    user -> user
                            .getAddress()
                            .stream()
                            .map(address -> new User2(user.getName(),
                                    address))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Uses `flatMap` to convert the stream into more elements, and the maps each address to a new `User2` with the given name, and converts it to a list. Had to use `<User2>` to force the `List<User2>`, which could be avoided by storing the `flatMap` lambda with its generics.

Additionally, added some getters and constructors which were implied by the code snippets. My full code is available at https://gist.github.com/kenzierocks/59685c564447b106f069.

Comment: `stream` & `collect` are annoying when we do small size data manipulation. check my another answer, maybe you'll like it!

Comment: @Stoneboy, in good Java-8 code there would be `User.addresses()` method which returns stream of addresses, so `.getAddress().stream()` will be single method call.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a library to make the code more elegant:

https://github.com/wapatesh/fig

Using this library, the code can be:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Seq<String> address; // need to change to seq to make best code
}

Seq<User> user = ...;
Seq<User2> result = user.flatMap(u -> u.getAddress().map(a->
                        new User2(u.getName(), a)));
```